# Displaying Complex Number

Tags: c#, tostring, complex-numbers

I have a complex number class with an override of ToString for output.

There are five cases for the structure of the complex number, each requiring a slightly different format for output:

```
a == 0, b == 0: "0"  
a == 0, b != 0: "bi"  
a != 0, b > 0: "a + bi"  
a != 0, b < 0: "a - |b|i"  
a != 0, b == 0: "a"
```

I have this and it works:

```
public override string ToString() {
            if (this.real == 0) {
                if (this.imaginary == 0) return "0";
                else return this.imaginary.ToString() + "i";
            }
            else {
                if (this.imaginary == 0) return this.real.ToString();
                else if(this.imaginary > 0) return this.real.ToString() + " + " + this.imaginary.ToString() + "i";
                else return this.real.ToString() + " - " + (this.imaginary * -1).ToString() + "i";
            }
        }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Maybe with less conditionals and possibly with less cases.

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just delete the if() statement, the else clause already does what you want.

Comment: I don't want stuff like 0 + 3i, I'd want that output as 3i

Comment: After some consideration: You want your four cases to be clearly readable. Therefore I'd go with if(a == 0 && b == 0) {...} else if (a==0 && b != 0) {...} else if (.... - that is, with else ifs that are on the same level, not spreading into a tree. The tree is slightly faster of course, but I don't think that this is an issue. Point is, the same levels with clear statements about their conditions give a perfect overview over what the function does.

Comment: I see. Would you say these are the correct four cases to be looking at as well? I'm not sure if there is some better more general way that maybe uses only three cases.

Comment: Sorry there are five cases. I added the fifth case to the question

Comment: Your fifth case includes your first case (suffices b == 0 : "a"). That said, I think four cases is the minimum. Except maybe if you do something that unites the third and fourth case by displaying a plus if a variable is above zero. I also think that you are overthinking this function.

Answer (score 0):

How about this??

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this.real != 0 && this.imaginary > 0) return this.real.ToString() + " + " + this.imaginary.ToString() + "i";
    if (this.real != 0 && this.imaginary < 0) return this.real.ToString() + " - " + (-1 * this.imaginary).ToString() + "i"; 
    if (this.real != 0 && this.imaginary == 0) return this.real.ToString();
    if (this.imaginary != 0) return this.imaginary.ToString() + "i";    
    return "0";     
}
```

Comment: Actually I think this fails on real numbers. It will return 0 in the case of a + 0i

Comment: If you change return "0"; to return this.real.ToString(); it works perfectly

Comment: I realize that if the imaginary part is 1, then we should also only be displaying i, rather than 1i. I handle this by replacing every instance of output of the imaginary part with a ternary that returns "" if the imaginary component is 1

Answer (score 0):

I took Andy Taw's logic, fixed the last case, and added some ternaries to cover the cases where b = +/- 1, in which case I don't even want to show b.

```
public override string ToString() {
            if (this.real != 0 && this.imaginary > 0) return this.real.ToString() + " + " + ((this.imaginary == 1)?"":this.imaginary.ToString()) + "i";
            else if (this.real != 0 && this.imaginary < 0) return this.real.ToString() + " - " + ((this.imaginary == -1)?"":(-1 * this.imaginary).ToString()) + "i";
            else if (this.imaginary != 0) return ((this.imaginary == 1)?"":((this.imaginary == -1)?"-":this.imaginary.ToString())) + "i";
            else return this.real.ToString();
        }
```